# Execute code on startup in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

Is there any way how I can execute some code only once after Airflow has started? I would like to configure how the logging is handled, but I can't find a way to initialize this configuration only once...

```
from utils import logger
logger.initialize()
```

It's basically these to lines (utils is a locally defined package). It works when I put these lines into one of the DAGs, but then the function is executed multiple times which is unnecessary...

Comment: its executed every time you import that package. put `logger.initialize()` somewhere inside main, where you actually want to initialize

Comment: The `logger.initialize()` function is not called on import, but only when I specifically call it.
What do you mean by somewhere inside main? Basically I want to those two lines to be executed exactly once. If I put them in a file with a DAG then they are executed all the time because Airflow reloads the DAGs periodically...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a module named `airflow_local_settings` that can be imported globally. Airflow's `airflow.settings` [attempts to load the module](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/settings.py#L305) during startup.

Comment: Can you import the file?

Comment: it does work, thank you very much. I was trying to load .yml file, and set env variables, so that all my env all located in single file, I'm targeting more to deplloy with several instances of airflow based on env file. The issue I noticed, is that I cannot put all env in singe file, because some env must be set before running the airflow instance. Is there a hook to do that ?